# Sketchapp Headers information

Tags: macos, plugins, sketchapp

I want to learn more about sketchapp to build a plugin for it, I was looking at the JSON files we can extract from a project and i noticed all the "classes" (i look them up and they show up as headers) tagged in it like: "MSRect", "MSColor", "MSExportOptions", etc.

I've looked at the sketchapp developer webpage, and some forums and i found some mentions to this classes but i couldn't get anything usefull at basic level.

The question would be, where i can find information about what are those classes and what they do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/abynim/Sketch-Headers, here I could find all the information i needed about this "classes", some one took the time to use the dump command to get all the information ( Methods, properties, etc.), and upload it to github.

This files took some time to understand and manage, but they solved all the problems i had with the creation of my plugin for Sketch.